# checking to see if files are executable perl

Tags: perl, file

I have a program that checks to see if the files in my directory are readable,writeable, and executable.

i have it set up so it looks like

```
if (-e $file){  
print "exists";  
}  

if (-x $file){  
print "executable";  
}
```

and so on

but my issue is when I run it it shows that the text files are executable too. Plain text files with 1 word in them. I feel like there is an error. What did I do wrong. I am a complete perl noob so forgive me.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve, If you want more conditionals (that is, to check if the file is also a text file), then you should include it in your if clause. Please edit your question to show us what exactly is the output you're getting and how it differs from what you expected

Comment: my issue is that when it checks the file to see if its executable, it comes up as it is. I dont think a regular text file is considered executable.

Comment: Did you do `ls -al` on the files? What do you see? Or is this on Windoze?

Comment: @JimGarrison is on mac, no I didnt to that, what does that do?

Comment: The `-l` option shows the filemode, which shows if the file is executable.  If the filemode contains “x” the file is executable.

Comment: To preempt the follow-up question: to find the executables as the operating system understands them, use http://p3rl.org/File::Which

Answer (score 2):

It is quite possible for a text file to be executable. It might not be particularly useful in many cases, but it's certainly possible.

In Unix (and your Mac is running a Unix-like operating system) the "executable" setting is just a flag that is set in the directory entry for a file. That flag can be set on or off for any file.

There are actually three of these permissions why record if you can read, write or execute a file. You can see these permissions by using the `ls -l` command in a terminal window (see [man ls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) for more details of what various `ls` options mean). There are probably ways to view these permissions in the Finder too (perhaps a "properties" menu item or something like that - I don't have a Mac handy to check).

You can change these permissions with the `chmod` ("change mode") command. See [man chmod](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) for details.

For more information about Unix file modes, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix)).

But whether or not a file is executable has nothing at all to do with its contents.

Answer (score -1):

The statement `if (-x $file)` does not check wether a file is an executable but if your user has execution priveleges on it.

For checking if a file is executable or not, **I'm affraid there isn't a magic method for it**. You may try to use:

> - `if (-T $file)` for checking if the file has an ASCII or UTF-8 enconding.
> - `if (-B $file)` for checking if the file is binary.

If this is unsuitable for your case, consider the following:

Assuming you are on a Linux enviroment, note that every file can be executed. The question here is:  The execution of e.g.: `test.txt`, is going to throw a standard error (STDERR)?

Most likely, it will.

If `test.txt` file contains:

`Some text`

And you launched it in your Perl script by: `system("./test.txt");` This will display a STDERR like:

`./test.txt: line 1: Some: command not found`

If for some reason you are looking to run all the files of your directory (in a for loop for instance) **be warned that this is pretty dangerous**, since you will launch all your files and you may not be willing to do so. Specially if the perl script is in the same directory that you are checking (this will lead to undesirable script behaviour).

Hope it helps ;)